# highcharts pie charts to have rounded corner in the path

Tags: highcharts

I am using pie chart type to build something like a speed meter type of chart like the example. Im looking for a way to make the path to have rounded corner instead of sharp 90 degree angle kinda.

am I using the right `chart type` or is there a better one that suits my application?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eatdoku/pnnrw3oq/1/)

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to have rounded.  Maybe an image of what you want in the end?

Comment: at the end of the slice, and the beginning of the slice, does that make sense?

Comment: You can also use [gauge](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer)

Comment: @Eatdoku This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297606/2499377